MySQL - Extraer ultimo registro de cada grupo en base a una fecha
MySQL. Como puedo extraer de la siguiente tabla el último turno registrado de cada persona en base a la fecha:
Ejemplo:
1122 | Vesp
1315 | Mat



clave
turno
fecha




1122
Vesp
08/12/24


1315
Mat
05/11/24


1122
Mat
05/11/24


1111
Noct
10/10/24


1315
Noct
25/04/24




algo como SELECT FROM tabla clave, turno, MAX(fecha) GROUP BY clave, turno?

A priori se me ocurre que utilices una subconsulta que saque la fecha más reciente por persona, y después hacerle un JOIN a la tabla original.
SELECT t.clave, t.turno, t.fecha
FROM tu_tabla t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT clave, MAX(fecha) AS max_fecha
    FROM tu_tabla
    GROUP BY clave
) m ON t.clave = m.clave AND t.fecha = m.max_fecha;

Básicamente, primero obtienes el último registro, es decir, la fecha más reciente por cada clave, y luego filtras la tabla original para quedarte solo con esos casos. Con eso ya deberías tener el último turno registrado de cada persona.
Conoce más:
TUTORIAL JOINS
SQL JOINS

Excelente! su funcionó! muchas gracias Adrian Otiz

Hola @LuisGuerra, si la respuesta te ayudo a resolver tu problema considera marcarla como aceptada. Podes realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar otra medalla. Saludos!
